# Avoid Promise constructor antipattern when logging

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I was looking at this question asked and the answer makes sense

[What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it#)

However if you just want to simply put a log message in the function or something simple is there any way of avoiding having to create a new promise like this

```
function getStuffDone(param) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // using a promise constructor
        myPromiseFn(param+1)
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log("getStuffDone executing");
            resolve(val);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("getStuffDone error");
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

And what if you also wanted a log message before the promise gets run in this position? Does this make things more difficult?

```
function getStuffDone(param) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // using a promise constructor
        console.log("getStuffDone starting");
        myPromiseFn(param+1)
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log("getStuffDone executing");
            resolve(val);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("getStuffDone error");
            reject(err);
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: Logging is not a special case. The "Explicit Promise Construction Anti-pattern" can and should be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return or rethrow the original value in your logging callbacks, and `then()` will give you back a promise of the same thing.

The whole point of promises is that they're easy to chain like that.

```
return myPromiseFn(param+1)
     .then(function(val) {
         console.log("getStuffDone executing");
         return val;
     }).catch(function(err) {
         console.log("getStuffDone error");
         throw err;
     });
```

Comment: I was still wondering about the edit I added to my question. In the scond case to accommodate the 'getStuffDone starting' log I would need to wrap it in a new comment? Though I guess the better solution is to go without the log in this case.

Comment: @user2802557: You can call that synchronously before calling the other function.

Answer (score 0):

What SLaks said. As an alternative to return/rethrow, it also works to *branch* your chain:

```
var p = myPromiseFn(param+1);
p.then(val => console.log("getStuffDone executing"),
       err => console.log("getStuffDone error"));
return p;
```

Each branch is an independent chain, so the logging does not affect the returned `p` in any way.